# ЧПУ и .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

Скажу сразу, что я почти в этом не разбираюсь. Необходимо сделать ЧПУ. Урлы типа `http://domein.com/model.php?id=`(название латиницей) нужно перевести в урлы типа `http://domein.com/model/`(название латиницей). В файле .htaccess выглядит так полностью:

```
php_flag register_globals on
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domein.com

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domein.com /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://domein.com / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ model/(.+)$ model.php?id =$1 [R]
```

И вот если ставить ключ [R] в последней строке, то редирект выполняется, т.е. в поле адреса забиваешь `http://domein.com/model/a` страница находиться, но при этом урл меняется на прежний `http://domein.com/model.php?id=a`. И когда из `http://domein.com/search.php` идет обращение к `http://domein.com/model.php?id=a`, урл сам не меняется на `http://domein.com/model/a`, хоть ты тресни.

С ключами отличными от [R]: либо [L], либо [QSA], либо их комбинации или же совсем без ключа; страница `http://domein.com/model/a` находиться и урл фиксируется, так что пользователь может его видеть. НО как и в случае с [R], урл сам не меняется на `http://domein.com/model/a`. И самое страшное что не грузятся картинки и невозможно перейти на другие ветки сайта, даже если менять `img src="images/img.jpg`" на `img src=" domein.com/images/img.jpg"` в итоге картинка имеет путь `http://domein.com/model/domein.com/images/img.jpg`, также и все страницы имеют ссылки вида `http://domein.com/model/index.php` вместо `http://domein.com/index.php` при обращении из изменённого урла к `index.php`.

Наверно немного запутанно, но смысл думаю понятен. Задача сделать рабочими ЧПУ, так чтобы новые урлы формировались из уровня выше и при этом сохранялись в поле адреса. И чтобы нормально грузились все картинки и пути были соответственно рабочими.

Повторюсь, я профан в этом деле и делаю только первые шаги в познании PHP. Так что просьба громко не смеяться. Буду благодарен за любой ответ.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ну а в скрипте уже разгребайте $_REQUEST['route']

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^model/([A-Za-z]+)$ model.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Чем не устроит такой редирект?

Соответственно для циферок:

```
RewriteRule ^model/([0-9]+)$ model.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Успехов!

Comment: Так я делал. Ошибка 404. Думаю, что дело не .htaccess. А вообще для меня главный вопрос будут ли при RewriteRule ^ model/(.+)$ model.php?id =$1 [R] вести себя поисковые машины? Будут ли они видеть изменённый ЧПУ?

Comment: Для того, чтобы все было ок для поисковиков, делайте редирект со старых типов урлов на новые, в том же самом .htaccess. Пример LifeStyle полностью должен работать. Хотя, лучше вот так: ^model/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$. Имейте ввиду, что в конце / нельзя ставить в данном случае, его нет в правиле.

Comment: Зато можно поставить "/?", тогда будет работать и "model/15", и "model/15/". Алсо, [R] означает "перенаправить" по аналогии с header('Location: model.php?id='.$id), а не "показать $2 вместо $1". + Дмитрий, "когда из http://domein.com/search.php идет обращение к http://domein.com/model.php?id=a, урл сам не меняется на http://domein.com/model/a, хоть ты тресни." все правильно, потому что обращаться надо к model/a. &lt;a href="/model/a">модель А</a>.

Comment: ЗЫ: mod_rewrite не занимается переписыванием "в обратную сторону". Т.е. это сделать можно, но трудновато будет в рекурсию не уйти. mod_rewrite обычно настривают на "по ЧПУ показать скрипт", а не по нормальной ссылке перенаправить на ЧПУ и потом показать скрипт. Короче, в скриптах своих надо писать ЧПУ, а их должен обрабатывать апач, во. <pre></pre> И уберите пробел из последнего правила)) "^ model[...]"