# Как сделать что бы вместо http://test1.ru/contacts.php было http://test1.ru/contacts?

Tags: javascript, php

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - создать скрипт http://test1.ru/contacts/index.php.
Тогда он будет отрабатывать по запросу http://test1.ru/contacts/?
Если нужно чтобы все осталось как есть, копай в сторону [mod_rewrite](http://rizloff.com/web/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know). Этот модуль на уровне веб-сервера может делать преобразование виртуального URI в реальный. А настраивается через .htaccess

Comment: Можно скрипт подсказать, я к сожелению не знаю js

Comment: Решение вопроса к JavaScript не имеет ни какого отношения. Все делается на стороне сервера.
Если скрипт contacts.php переименовать в index.php и перенести в директорию contacts/ (на сервере), то он будет отзываться по адресу http://test1.ru/contacts/. И параметры, соответственно, можно будет задавать следующим образом http://test1.ru/contacts/?a=1&b=2.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте поиск. Вот похожая [тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14083/%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83-%D0%B8-htaccess?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1).

Answer (score 0):

Включите Options MultiViews, если вы используете сервер Apache.