# Как реализовать ЧПУ

Tags: php, cms, чпу

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать ЧПУ на самописном CMS?
Идея такая, что страницы открываются всегда через `index.php` посредством GET запроса, например: `index.php?action=pages&category=animals&article=123`.

Я хочу реализовать следующую схему:
Скрыть `index.php` из SEF
Системные GET переменные "захардкодить", напр. pages, category
А динамические, типа название статьи, прописывать в самой статье и брать оттуда (с пониманием "откуда" беда - не понимаю как .htaccess будет забирать мое "кастомное" значение ссылки из статьи), результат: mysite.com/pages/category/animals/my-custom-sef-article-name

Не могу найти примера. Help.
P.S.: Что-то подобное видел давно в Joomla

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому, что примеров в google и на ru.stackoverflow.com полным полно. Пожалуйста пользуйтесь поиском прежде, чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: @Alex, если есть примеры на _ru.stackoverflow.com_, то закрывать надо как дубликат

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ЧПУ и .htaccess](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14083/%d0%a7%d0%9f%d0%a3-%d0%b8-htaccess)