# скрытие get запроса

Tags: html, .htaccess

как скрыть запрос в .htaccess
что бы

```
https://domain.ru/?s=page3
стал
https://domain.ru/page3
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ЧПУ и .htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14083/%d0%a7%d0%9f%d0%a3-%d0%b8-htaccess)

Comment: Почему сразу нельзя передать линк `https://domain.ru/page3`?